# Why can't I join Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS to my windows 2016 server?

Tags: networking, server, permissions

I'm using VMware, i have both machines in the same LAN. Everything pings properly. When I try to join the following happens.

```
root@ubuntu:~# realm join -U Administrador martindom.eus --verbose
* Resolving: _ldap._tcp.martindom.eus
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.1.1.2
 * Successfully discovered: martindom.eus
Password for Administrador: 
 * Unconditionally checking packages
 * Resolving required packages
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain martindom.eus --domain-realm MARTINDOM.EUS --domain-controller 10.1.1.2 --login-type user --login-user Administrador --stdin-password
 * Using domain name: martindom.eus
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: UBUNTU
 * Using domain realm: martindom.eus
 * Sending NetLogon ping to domain controller: 10.1.1.2
 * Received NetLogon info from: WIN-6CD5GTHS432.martindom.eus
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-rNHXbG/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-goD3oE
 * Authenticated as user: Administrador@MARTINDOM.EUS
 * Using GSS-SPNEGO for SASL bind
 ! Couldn't authenticate to active directory: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Ticket expired)
adcli: couldn't connect to martindom.eus domain: Couldn't authenticate to active directory: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Ticket expired)
 ! Insufficient permissions to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Insufficient permissions to join the domain
```

The Administrador user is the default user for administrator so i don't really understand how can I not have the neccesary permissions.

Any input will be apreciated.